# From Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) to Response content not in json format in python

Tags: python

```
res = self.session.post(url=self.url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=self.h, verify=False)
try:
    js = res.json()
    token = js['token']
    self.cookie['reese84'] = token
    print(fg + ' (success)')
    return token
except ValueError:
    print("Response content is not valid JSON")
```

I am getting this :

[*] Fetching Token Response content is not valid JSON

Would be appreciated if someone help me out

I am expecting the Jason response but not receiving

Comment: is  the url response is json?, you can print and check

Comment: This particular error message usually indicates that you received an empty response.